# Current Count vs Total Count output in a single line using Bash

Tags: bash, loops

I need an output of current count vs total count in single line. I would like to know if this could be done Via Bash using 'for' 'while' loop.

Expecting an output that should only update the count and should not display multiple lines

File Content

```
$ cat ~/test.rtf
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
hostname4
```

```
#!/bin/sh

j=1
k=$(cat ~/test.rtf | wc -l)

for i in $(cat ~/test.rtf);
do
echo "Working on line ($j/$k)"
echo "$i" 
#or any other command for i

j=$((j+1))

done
```

EX:

```
Working on line (2/4)
```

Not like,

```
Working on line (2/4)
Working on line (3/4)
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=greybot&titlesearch=Titles#BashFAQ.2F001.How_can_I_read_a_file_.28data_stream.2C_variable.29_line-by-line_.28and.2For_field-by-field.29.3F

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but it will not make a difference to the output. Will it?

Comment: The right tool to use is what you can read. Not `for` loop

Comment: please update the question with a few sample lines from `test.rtf` and the expected output; as currently coded you have 2 `echo` calls in your script but you only show the output from one `echo` call ... so it's not clear what we're supposed to do with the output from that 2nd `echo` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- OP wants to generate `n` lines of output that overwrite each other on successive passes through the loop
- in OP's sample code there are two `echo` calls so in this case `n=2`

General approaches:

- issue a `clear` at the beginning of each pass through the loop so as to clear the current output and reposition the cursor at the 'top' of the console/window
- use `tput` to manage movement of the cursor (and clearing/overwriting of previous output)

Sample input:

```
$ cat test.rtf
this is line1
then line2
and line3
and last but not least line4
real last line5
```

**`clear`** approach:

```
j=1
k=$(wc -l < test.rtf)

while read -r line
do
    clear
    echo "Working on line ($j/$k)"
    echo "${line}"
    ((j++))
done < test.rtf
```

**`tput`** approach:

```
j=1
k=$(wc -l < test.rtf)

EraseToEOL=$(tput el)                             # grab terminal specific code for clearing from cursor to EOL

clear                                             # optional: start with a new screen otherwise use current position in console/window for next command ...
tput sc                                           # grab current cursor position

while read -r line
do
    tput rc                                       # go (back) to cursor position stored via 'tput sc'
    echo "Working on line ($j/$k)"
    echo "${line}${EraseToEOL}"                   # ${EraseToEOL} forces clearing rest of line, effectively erasing a previous line that may have been longer then the current line of output
    ((j++))
done < test.rtf
```

Both of these generate the same result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't think of with a 'clear' mind I would say :). But the tput was news to me.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
file=~/test.rtf
nl=$(wc -l "$file")
nl=${nl%%[[:blank:]]*}
i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    i=$((i+1))
    echo "Working on line ($i/$nl)"
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main question is how to avoid each the counter to be written to new lines. The newlines are `\n` characters, which is appended by `echo`. You want `\r`, like

```
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do 
  printf "Counter $i\r"
  sleep 1
done
echo
```

When you `echo` something from the line you are working on, you will use `\n` again. I will use `cut` as an example of processing the inputline. Use the output string in the same `printf` command like

```
j=1
k=$(cat ~/test.rtf | wc -l)

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf "Working on line (%s): %s\r" "$j/$k" $(cut -c1-10 <<< "${line}")
  sleep 1
  ((j++))
done < ~/test.rft
```

The problem with the above solution is that you will see output from previous lines when your last output is shorter than the previous one. When you know the maximum length that your processing of the line will show, you can force additional spaces:

```
j=1
k=$(cat ~/test.rtf | wc -l)

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf "Working on line (%5.5s): %-20s\r" "$j/$k" "$(cut -c1-20 <<< "${line}")"; 
  sleep 1
  ((j++))
done < ~/test.rft
```

Comment: I think you men `((j++))` or `j=$((j+1))` and not plain `j++` yes?

Comment: Thanks for this answer as well. It works for my script too... since all the words in the lines in my file have the same number of chars. But I felt the other solution suited my requirement if I had a few more printing statements.